# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost, on MySQL 5.7

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, localhost

Today I've installed MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04 after the installation it shows ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost, how to resolve this please let me know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had understand your problem while submitting the query. This is the very nice solution for your problem.

Please check it here:https://www.expresstechsoftwares.com/mysql-access-denied-user-root-localhost/

Cheers
Ryan

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and type the following commands as exactly as shown:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Logging in using MySQL Workbench was successful for me after this.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup Temp Environment to access MySQL**

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"    
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

**Login in MySQL**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**Update Password**

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('123') WHERE user='root';
```

**Flush Previous Privileges & Grant All**

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```